# Sync two textboxes with different models

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have a simple angular app with two textboxes with different models

```
First Email: <input ng-model="firstEmail"/>
Second Email: <input ng-model="secondEmail"/>
```

Now, if something is typed in first email, I want it to get populated in second email but if second email is manually edited, then this binding should stop i.e. further changes in first email should't affect second email.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var emailApp = angular.module('emailApp', []);
emailApp.controller('EmailCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="emailApp">
  <div ng-controller="EmailCtrl">
      First Email: <input ng-model="firstEmail"/>
      <br>
      Second Email: <input ng-model="secondEmail"/>
      </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use watch to bind the content in secondEmail from the firstEmail.

```
  $scope.$watch('firstEmail',function(newVal,oldVal){
    $scope.secondEmail=newVal;
    })
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g36coACBVDDmhqENeu1V?p=preview)

Comment: @squiroid Great man +1..We could add true in watch if it is collection :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-change` directive to update the value.

```
<body ng-app="emailApp">
  <div ng-controller="EmailCtrl">
      First Email: <input ng-model="firstEmail" ng-change="secondEmail=firstEmail"/>
      <br>
      Second Email: <input ng-model="secondEmail"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VQG5LPVnz6WIaj0yez26?p=preview)

This could help you. Thanks.

Comment: thanks. its also a correct answer. but answer by squiroid exactly solves my requirement as I need to refer oldvalue as well

Comment: @dusk7 Yeah.You're welcome. ng-change avoids the dirty checking. like $watch does..if you want oldValues then you need to go for `$watch` as @squiroid suggested :)