# Angularjs - assigning logic between two models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angular. It is a very simple question - 
in my index.html I am defining two models on two text boxes :-

```
<html><head><script...></head><body ng-app="myApp"ng-controller="MainController" >  

<input ng-model="tb1"  type="text"  name="numberofusers"/>
 <input  ng-model="tb2" type="text"></input>

</body></html>
```

And in my app.js I am defining like this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.tb1 = $scope.tb2;

}]);
```

Now, what I want is that whatever I type in first text box (tb1) automatically typed to second text box (tb2) and vise-versa, but that is not happening.

Any guess ?

Comment: this is the same what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497407/sync-two-textboxes-with-different-models/28497770#28497770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because controller will only execute once and if there is any value in $scope.tb2 will assign to $scope.tb1 but intially both of them are blank .
So you need to $watch the changes and assign value to each other like :-

```
$scope.$watch('tb1',function(newVal){
$scope.tb2=newVal;
})

$scope.$watch('tb2',function(newVal){
$scope.tb1=newVal;
})
```

And if you want to manage it on front end you can use ng-change directive like

```
<input ng-model="tb1"  type="text" ng-change="tb2=tb1" name="numberofusers"/>
 <input  ng-model="tb2" type="text" ng-change="tb1=tb2"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked.. And no, I don't want to manage it from front end.. 
Just bringing to notice a little typo in your code - $scope.$watch('tb1',function(newVal)){...  should be $scope.$watch('tb1',function(newVal){....

Comment: oops sorry great you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in controller `$scope.tb1 = $scope.tb2;` would only be executed once (when controller initializes), that's why it doesn't work.

You need to bind input elements to the same `model` then Angular will handle two-way binding for you automatically.

```
<input ng-model="tb1"  type="text"  name="numberofusers"/>
<input ng-model="tb1" type="text"></input>
```

Or if you want to use two different models for different elements, you can add a hook to `input`'s `ng-change` event listener like

```
<input ng-model="tb1"  type="text"  name="numberofusers" ng-change="tb2 = tb1"/>
<input  ng-model="tb2" type="text" ng-change="tb1 = tb2"></input>
```

Then these two elements would sync automatically. But you know what, `ng-change` can only monitor user input change, that means, if you change `tb1` or `tb2` programmably, `ng-change` will not be triggered.

In this case, you should monitor model's change using `$scope.$watch`

```
$scope.$watch('tb1', function(newValue) {
  $scope.tb2 = newValue;
}));
```

Currently it's beyond your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two-way binding to achieve that. An example is: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7t984sf9/8/)

Create your directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myName = 'Carl';
}).directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: { 
            twowayBindingProp: '=myName'
        }
    }
});
```

And bind it through:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>From parent: </h1>
    <h3>parentProp2: <input ng-model="myName"></h3>
    <div my-directive my-name="myName">
        <h1>From child: </h1>
        <h3>twowayBindingProp: {{ twowayBindingProp }}</h3>
        <h1>Set from child:</h1> 
        twowayBindingProp： <input ng-model="twowayBindingProp">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```